# Why is geth console returning me a transaction hash when I try to read my contract storage variable instead of actual value(uint256)?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, web3js, geth-debugging

**Environment :**

Running an Ethereum private network of one node using Geth
Connected to Remix-IDE at localhost:8545

Contract successfully deployed and tested via Remix

**Contract Code :**

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0

pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

contract Storage {
    uint256 number;

    function store(uint256 num) public {
        number = num;
    }

    function retrieve() public view returns (uint256){
        return number;
    }
}
```

**Geth Console :**

```
// initialising my contract instance 
const storage = eth.contract(storage_abi).at(storage_address)

// calling non-const method in storage contract 
storage.store(10)
// returns txn hash and updates number in storage contract

// calling const(pure) method in storage contract 
storage.retrieve()
// returns a txn hash instead of returning number
```

**Problem :**

In Geth console, I am not getting 10 -> expected behaviour.

Instead getting a txn hash for a const method invoke -> unexpected behaviour.

Do I need to use web3 in geth console and .call() or something ?

**Solved :**

Need to use .call()

const value = await myContractInstance.methods.(<methodParams…>).call();

```
storage.retrieve.call();
// returns the storage variable number correctly
```

Comment: Solved: indeed you have to use web3.<methodName>.call() to get expected result !